# PHP Codeigniter: Is there an elegant way to to get the SMTP return code upon a mail failure

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

When using the standard Codeigniter

```
mail->send()
```

it only returns TRUE or FALSE.  However, I have requirements to handle certain SMTP return codes differently.  I could parse out of the debug text info, or somehow try to override the mail handler for Codeigniter.  Is there any straight forward and elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a build in mechanism for this in CodeIgniter. What you could do is extend the CI email class and add a function to expose the protected `_debug_msg` array.

If you look at the source of email class you will see that `print_debugger()` function is converting `_debug_msg` array into string. So if `_debug_msg` has what you are looking for then you wouldn't have to parse any string.

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public get_msg()
    {
        if (count($this->_debug_msg) > 0)
        {
            return $this->_debug_msg;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Refer the following link on how to extend CI libs
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer without even checking it, because it makes sense (and I was going to try something like this anyways).  But I'll let you know if there are problems!

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending emails using `sendmail` you may not be able to get the SMTP return codes until later.

The way to get bounces (I'm guessing?) is by adding a `Return-Path` to your outgoing emails and choose an email inbox that's manned by `procmail`, so that you can pipe the feedback emails back into PHP to parse it.

Let me know if you need more details on the above.

Comment: Well, bounces are another issue, but we are going to handle them by doing a sweep for them later.  Thanks!